# How to turn row headers into a single column in R?

Tags: r

I am working with data with multiple row headers. I am willing to add these headers into data.

EX:
I want to change this

```
    X 
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
```

into this

```
Y X
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
```

I want to keep Y and X as headers but make A,B,C,D,E are column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rownames_to_column` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    rownames_to_column("Y")
```

-output

```
#  Y X
#1 A 1
#2 B 2
#3 C 3
#4 D 4
#5 E 5
```

---

Or with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Y = row.names(df1), X = df1$X)
```

-output

```
#  Y X
#1 A 1
#2 B 2
#3 C 3
#4 D 4
#5 E 5
```

NOTE: Both are single line codes

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
#Code
new <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y=rownames(df),df),row.names = NULL)
rownames(new)<-NULL
```

Output:

```
new
  Y X
1 A 1
2 B 2
3 C 3
4 D 4
5 E 5
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(X = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"))
```